# Which is a more common way, 10+ or 10 then + as superscript?

Tags: orthography, typography, superscripts

I don't know which shortened form of "10 or more" is more appropriate, is it 10+ or 10<sup>+</sup> (i.e. with the plus sign as superscript). What do you think?

Extra question, when do we use superscript in English,well, aside from ordinal numbers and references?

Comment: Neither variant has currency in formal official writing that I'm aware of. *10+*, "ten plus" is understood in informal shorthand, chat and the like. What context do you have in mind? Super- and subscript are imitations of hand-written shorthand that has little connection to chat shorthand, probably only used by geeks. *+1* "plus one" has become an idiom for "you and *and one more*"; "ten plus" doesn't strike me as a probable verbal idiom, rather a purely technical symbolism. *10 to the power of plus* is effectively *10x*, the multiplicative series of ten, in some algebraic notation.

Comment: >=10 is what I’d use as shorthand.

Comment: "10+" is shorthand for "ten plus," not "10 or more."   That said, "10+" is always what you'd write to mean that, never superscript.

Answer (score 2):

10+ is sometimes used as a shorthand for 10 or more. Do not superscript the +.

A superscript + is normally only used for positively charged ions or particles: H<sup>+</sup> for hydrogen ions, Na<sup>+</sup> for natrium ions, K<sup>+</sup> for potassium ions, Zn<sup>2+</sup> for zinc ions, H<sub>3</sub>O<sup>+</sup> for hydronium ions, NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup> for ammonium ions, e<sup>+</sup> for positrons, 
μ<sup>+</sup> for antimuons.

Otherwise, superscripts are used:

- in mathematics, for exponents: 10<sup>6</sup> is a million, 1 m<sup>2</sup> is a squared metre
- for footnotes
- for the abbreviations TM (trade mark) and SM (service mark) following a trade mark or a service mark
- for digits behind the decimal point or comma: $1.<sup>50</sup>
- for the final letters of ordinals: 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup>
- for the final letters of abbreviations that contain the first and final letters: M<sup>lle</sup> for *mademoiselle*, M<sup>r</sup> for *monsieur* or mister, D<sup>r</sup> for doctor

Modern style guides advise against the use of superscripts in the last three points.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen that usage of 10+ with a superscript as 10<sup>+</sup>.

Wikipedia says in [Subscript and superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript)

> In English, most nontechnical use of superiors is archaic.

although I do still see (and sometimes use) superscript for ordinals like 10<sup>th</sup>.

But it comes down to a matter of preferred style.